# how to get the number of records in excel vba recordeset

Tags: sql, excel, vba, recordset

I want to get the total number of records in a record set using vba in excel, i used below code but it not running . maybe help me!

```
 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" &   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\infodb.mdb"
    cn.Open strConnection

strSql = "SELECt * FROM tbl_hoze"
        Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
            rs.MoveLast
            MsgBox rs.RecordCount
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Where? What's the exact problem you're having with your code?

Comment: If you just want the count then `strSql = "SELECT count(*) as numRecs FROM tbl_hoze"` should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your SQL statement is executed successfully and you get the recordset, I would get the rows in an array and use the array to do whatever I want. RecordCount function fails sometimes, this has happened to me often.

Moreover, I don't know why you are using rs.MoveLast before you wanted to print the number of records. Delete it or move it to after msgbox line and see what happens. In short, you would do this:

```
dim arr() as variant

arr=rs.GetRows()
```

Comment: hi, if i remove  rs.MoveLast it show me -1 in result

Comment: i use below code bu the result is incorrect:         `strSql = "SELECt * FROM tbl_hoze"
        Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
        arr = rs.GetRows()
        MsgBox UBound(arr)`

Comment: @sasanmohammadi `.GetRows() ` returns a 2D array with the columns being the first dimension and the rows the second.  `MsgBox UBound(arr, 2)` will return the row count.  Alternative, you could transpose the array: `arr = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)`

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem whenever I'm working with a SQL Server DB (not so much with Access). So I've worked out this quick function that should be able to give you the row count of a SQL Server Recordset.

```
Private Function GetSQLRecordCount(rs As Recordset) As Integer

    Dim retVal As Integer: retVal = 0
    On Error GoTo NOROWSRETURNED
        Dim counterArray() As Variant: counterArray = rs.GetRows()
        retVal = UBound(counterArray, 2) - LBound(counterArray, 2) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    GetSQLRecordCount = retVal

    Exit Function
NOROWSRETURNED:
    retVal = 0
    GetSQLRecordCount = retVal

End Function
```

I've been using this frequently recently, and it's been pretty solid.